# tf.data: Parallelize loading step

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a data input pipeline that has:

- input datapoints of types that are not castable to a `tf.Tensor` (dicts and whatnot)
- preprocessing functions that could not understand tensorflow types and need to work with those datapoints; some of which do data augmentation on the fly

I've been trying to fit this into a `tf.data` pipeline, and I'm stuck on running the preprocessing for multiple datapoints in parallel. So far I've tried this:

- use `Dataset.from_generator(gen)` and do the preprocessing in the generator; this works but it processes each datapoint sequentially, no matter what arrangement of `prefetch` and fake `map` calls I patch on it. Is it impossible to prefetch in parallel?
- encapsulate the preprocessing in a `tf.py_function` so I could `map` it in parallel over my Dataset, but

  1. this requires some pretty ugly (de)serialization to fit exotic
     types into string tensors,
  2. apparently the execution of the `py_function` would be handed over to the (single-process) python interpreter, so I'd be stuck with the python GIL which would not help me much
- I saw that you could do some tricks with `interleave` but haven't found any which does not have issues from the first two ideas.

Am I missing anything here? Am I forced to either modify my preprocessing so that it can run in a graph or is there a way to multiprocess it?

Our previous way of doing this was using keras.Sequence which worked well but there's just too many people pushing the upgrade to the `tf.data` API. *(hell, even trying the keras.Sequence with tf 2.2 yields `WARNING:tensorflow:multiprocessing can interact badly with TensorFlow, causing nondeterministic deadlocks. For high performance data pipelines tf.data is recommended.`)*

*Note: I'm using tf 2.2rc3*

Comment: `Dataset.from_generator(gen)` is not parallelized regardless of the `use_multiprocessing` and `workers` parameters in `model.fit`. (tf 2.1.0)

Comment: Considering the volatility of the `tf.data` API and its internals, I guess subclassing `Dataset`, `DatasetSource` or implementing a custom `from_generator` would not be very productive?

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I agree with you from looking at the code, I don't think implementing our own `from_generator` on our side would be a good move. Maybe a contribution to tensorflow would be worth a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across the same problem and found a (relatively) easy solution.

It turns out that the proper way to do so is indeed to first create a `tf.data.Dataset` object using the `from_generator(gen)` method, before applying your custom python processing function (wrapped within a `py_function`) with the `map` method. As you mentioned, there is a trick to avoid serialization / deserialization of the input.

The trick is to use a generator which will only generates the indexes of your training set. Each called training index will be passed to the wrapped py_function, which can in return evaluate your original dataset at that index. You can then process your datapoint and return your processed data to the rest of your `tf.data` pipeline.

```
def func(i):
    i = i.numpy() # decoding from the EagerTensor object
    x, y = processing_function(training_set[i])
    return x, y # numpy arrays of types uint8, float32

z = list(range(len(training_set))) # the index generator

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: z, tf.uint8)

dataset = dataset.map(lambda i: tf.py_function(func=func, inp=[i], 
                                               Tout=[tf.uint8, tf.float32]), 
                      num_parallel_calls=12)

dataset = dataset.batch(1)
```

Note that in practice, depending on the model you train your dataset on, you will probably need to apply another `map` to your dataset after the `batch`:

```
def _fixup_shape(x, y):
    x.set_shape([None, None, None, nb_channels])
    y.set_shape([None, nb_classes])
    return x, y
dataset = dataset.map(_fixup_shape)
```

This is a known issue which seems to be due to the incapacity of the `from_generator` method to infer the shape properly in some cases. Hence you need to pass the expected output shape explicitly. For more information:

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32912
- [as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape on y_t_rank = len(y_t.shape.as_list()) and related to metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62585490/as-list-is-not-defined-on-an-unknown-tensorshape-on-y-t-rank-leny-t-shape-a))

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add `batch()` before `map()` in your input pipeline.

It is usually meant to reduce the overhead of the map function call for small map function, see here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#vectorizing_mapping

However you can also use it to get a batch of input to your map `py_function` and use python `multiprocessing` there to speed things up.

This way you can get around the GIL limitations which makes `num_parallel_calls` in  `tf.data.map()` useless for `py_function` map functions.

Comment: I thought it is not recommend to use multiprocessing with Tensrflow. I actually encounter many errors when trying to do it. Anyone has successful experience with such combination?