# Getting ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape. but the as_list() works fine on (next(iter(dataset)))

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras

I'm trying to use `tf.data.Dataset.list_files` to load `.tiff` images and infer their labels from their names.

I use the following code but stumbled upon a strange issue, as described bellow:

```
import os
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import cv2


DATA_PATH = Path('PATH TO DATA')
BATCH_SIZE = 32
INPUT_IMAGE_SHAPE = (128, 128, 1)
CROP_SHAPE = INPUT_IMAGE_SHAPE
CENTRAL_CROP_PROP = .7
BRIGHTNESS_DELTA = 0.1
CONTRAST = (0.4, 0.6)

class ConvModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, input_shape):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_image_shape = input_shape
        self.model = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Input(shape=input_shape),
            layers.Conv2D(32, 3),
            layers.BatchNormalization(),
            layers.ReLU(),
            layers.MaxPool2D(),
            layers.Conv2D(64, 5),
            layers.BatchNormalization(),
            layers.ReLU(),
            layers.MaxPool2D(),
            layers.Conv2D(128, 3, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)),
            layers.BatchNormalization(),
            layers.ReLU(),
            layers.Flatten(),
            layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)),
            layers.Dropout(0.5),
            layers.Dense(10)
        ])

    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.model(inputs)


def preprocessing_func(image):
    img = tf.image.central_crop(image, CENTRAL_CROP_PROP)
    if img.shape[2] == 3:
        img = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(img)
    return img


def augment(image):
    img = tf.image.random_crop(image, size=CROP_SHAPE)  # Slices a shape size portion out of value at a uniformly chosen offset. Requires value.shape >= size.
    img = tf.image.random_brightness(img, max_delta=BRIGHTNESS_DELTA)  # Equivalent to adjust_brightness() using a delta randomly picked in the interval [-max_delta, max_delta)
    img = tf.image.random_contrast(img, lower=CONTRAST[0], upper=CONTRAST[1])  # Equivalent to adjust_contrast() but uses a contrast_factor randomly picked in the interval [lower, upper).
    img = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(img)
    img = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(img)

    return img


def load_image(image_file):
    # 1) Decode the path
    image_file = image_file.decode('utf-8')

    # 2) Read the image
    img = cv2.imread(image_file)
    if len(img.shape) < 3:
        img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=-1)
    img = preprocessing_func(image=img)
    img = augment(img)
    img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32)
    img.set_shape(INPUT_IMAGE_SHAPE)
    # 3) Get the label
    label = tf.strings.split(image_file, "\\")[-1]
    label = tf.strings.substr(label, pos=0, len=1)
    label = tf.strings.to_number(label, out_type=tf.float32)
    label = tf.cast(label, tf.float32)
    label.set_shape([])
    return img, label

def _fixup_shape(images, labels):
    images.set_shape(INPUT_IMAGE_SHAPE)
    labels.set_shape([])
    return images, labels

if __name__=='__main__':
    train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(DATA_PATH / '*.tiff'))
    train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x: tf.numpy_function(load_image, [x], (tf.float32, tf.float32)))
    # train_ds = train_ds.map(_fixup_shape)
    train_ds = train_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
    train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    train_ds = train_ds.repeat()

    model = ConvModel(input_shape=INPUT_IMAGE_SHAPE)
    model.compile(
        loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-4),
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )

    train_log_dir = f'./logs/{dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")}/train_data'
    callbacks = [
        keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
            log_dir=train_log_dir,
            write_images=True
        )
    ]

    model.fit(
        train_ds,
        batch_size=32,
        steps_per_epoch=10,
        epochs=10,
        callbacks=callbacks
    )
```

While I try to run it it throws up an error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-213-b1f3d317135b> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(
      2     train_ds,
      3     batch_size=32,
      4     steps_per_epoch=10,
      5     epochs=10,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1127           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1128             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1129               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1130             else:
   1131               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\mchls\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 878, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\mchls\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 867, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\mchls\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 860, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\mchls\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 817, in train_step
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\mchls\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 439, in update_state
        self.build(y_pred, y_true)
    File "C:\Users\mchls\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 359, in build
        self._metrics = tf.__internal__.nest.map_structure_up_to(y_pred, self._get_metric_objects,
    File "C:\Users\mchls\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 485, in _get_metric_objects
        return [self._get_metric_object(m, y_t, y_p) for m in metrics]
    File "C:\Users\mchls\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 485, in <listcomp>
        return [self._get_metric_object(m, y_t, y_p) for m in metrics]
    File "C:\Users\mchls\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 506, in _get_metric_object
        y_t_rank = len(y_t.shape.as_list())

    ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.
```

though manually running `X.shape.as_list()` and `y.shape.as_list()` works, as shown below:

```
X, y = next(iter(train_ds))
X.shape.as_list(), y.shape.as_list()
[OUT] ([16, 128, 128, 1], [16])
```

This issue is fixed, as described in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32912) and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65895992/4596078), by manually mapping the following function on the `dataset` by `train_ds = train_ds.map(_fixup_shape).batch(BATCH_SIZE)`:

```
def _fixup_shape(images, labels):
    images.set_shape([128, 128, 1])
    labels.set_shape([]) # I have 19 classes
    # weights.set_shape([None])
    return images, labels

if __name__=='__main__':
    train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(DATA_PATH / '*.tiff'))
    train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x: tf.numpy_function(load_image, [x], (tf.float32, tf.float32)))
    train_ds = train_ds.map(_fixup_shape)
    train_ds = train_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
    train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    train_ds = train_ds.repeat()
```

but I can't figure out why is the `_fixup_shape` is needed in the first place, as I do state the shape inside the `load_image` function.

Is it a bug in TF 2.6.1 or is it an expected behavior?

Thanks