# Parallel data extraction with generators and tf.data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a huge dataset (1TB) with thousand of small **hdf5** files, each consisting out of two 3D **numpy** arrays (only float64 numbers), which currently are fetched by a generator which is given to the `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` function:

```py
def generator(files):
    for file in files:
        with h5py.File(file, 'r') as hf:
            epsilon = hf['epsilon'][()]
            field = hf['field'][()]
        yield epsilon, field

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator, args=[files],output_signature=(
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=s[0], dtype=tf.float64),     #s[0] e.g. (120,100,60,1)
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=s[1], dtype=tf.float64)))    #s[1] e.g. (120,100,60,6)

dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10).repeat(args.ep).batch(args.bs).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Unfortunately, I have a data bottleneck. Now I want to parallel extract from my datasets to utilize all my 64 CPUs. There was a similar post: [tf.data: Parallelize loading step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61370108/tf-data-parallelize-loading-step), but I couldn't figure out what I did wrong.

Does anyone know how to handle this problem?

**UPDATE**

```
def load_hdf5_file(filename):
    filename = tf.strings.reduce_join(filename, separator="").numpy().decode("utf-8")
    with h5py.File(filename, 'r') as hf:
        # Access the datasets within the file
        epsilon = hf['epsilon'][()]
        field = hf['field'][()]

    return epsilon, field



# List of HDF5 filenames
filenames = glob.glob(f'{args.p_data}/*.h5')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
num_parallel_calls = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(load_hdf5_file, [x], Tout=(tf.float32, tf.float32)), num_parallel_calls=num_parallel_calls)
```

As Tim Roberts pointed out, my reading speed is probably just too low. Additionally, the tf_pyfunc is only using one core and I don't know how to parallelize it.

Comment: The limiting factor here is probably the disk speed.  Even on a fast disk, it takes a long time to read 1TB of data, and parallelism cannot reduce that time.  What are you going to DO with the data?  You probably don't have 1TB of RAM to store these.

Comment: I wan to to train my U-Net CNN with it. Normally I use 600GB of RAM (computing on a High Performance Cluster: 8xA100, 64 CPUS, 600GB of usable RAM, 950GB in total for this specific node). Diskspeed is displayed as 6GB/s. Caching the dataset is possible until this 600GB, after that need to go other ways, but I dont know the answer.

Comment: What you're doing above takes almost no processor time, right?  You are strictly I/O bound.  It's going to take 3 or 4 minutes at top speed to read that data from disk, and parallelization cannot help that.