# tf.data from_generator wont cache two datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a large training dataset of 400GB, a validation set of 50GB, and a RAM capacity of 950GB. Since these datasets are quite large, I'm using the from_generator function in TensorFlow's tf.data.Dataset to fetch them using a generator. To improve performance, I'm caching the datasets using the tf.data.Dataset.cache() function. Without caching it takes way too long and wouldn't be feasible.

While the caching works well for the training dataset, I'm experiencing issues with fetching the validation set. In each epoch, the validation set is loaded from the disk instead of being properly fetched and cached.

```
def generator(files, m):
    for file in files:
        with h5py.File(file, 'r') as hf:
            epsilon = hf['epsilon'][()]
            field = hf['field'][()]
            field = [scaler(x, m) for x in field]
        yield epsilon, field

def scaler(x, m):
    return (2*((x-m[0])/(m[1]-m[0])))-1

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(pygen.generator, args=[files,minmax],output_signature=(
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=s[0], dtype=tf.float32),
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=s[1], dtype=tf.float32)))

val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(pygen.generator, args=[val_files,minmax],output_signature=(
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=s[0], dtype=tf.float32),
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=s[1], dtype=tf.float32)))

dataset = dataset.take(len(files)).cache().batch(args.bs).repeat(args.ep)
val_dataset = val_dataset.take(len(val_files)).cache().batch(args.bs).repeat(args.ep)

strategy = tf.distribute.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
   m = unet65.build(s[0])
   m.fit(dataset,validation_data=val_dataset, epochs=args.ep, steps_per_epoch = spe,callbacks[model_checkpoint_callback,model_csv_logger,model_tensorboard,model_earlystopping_unet65])
```

Does anyone know how to accelerate the the validation set fetching? I also tried parallel fetching with num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE and prefetch ([enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76183952/parallel-data-extraction-with-generators-and-tf-data)), but nothing seems to work fast enough.